# how to handle 'Close' Event of a Group Box in C#

Tags: c#

Someone let me know how to handle Group Box Close event, as i didn't see any event handler for this in .net.

Comment: You may have to customize it and provide a close option, still i dont see why you have to close it. Its just a template or a container.

Comment: yes Cancel option is there. but if user selects Close then grpbox will be closed, but i want to call  another function on Close option click.

Comment: Yes. On WinForm Menu, contains Login option. when User Selects a grpbox will open. I want to handle the grpbox close event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GroupBox`es are strictly visual elements, used to group related controls together on a form. By default, there is no way to close them, so there's no event to handle.

If you want to hide the box for some reason, you're allowed to handle its `Click` event, and change its visibility there.

**Updated**: If you want to handle your dialog box being closed, you can handle either the `Closing` event (to perform work prior to the box closing) or the `Closed` event (to perform work after the box has closed.)

You can add the handler in your `Form`'s constructor:

```
public void MyForm()
{
    this.Closing += MyClosingHandler;
    this.Closed += MyClosedHandler;
}

private void MyClosingHandler(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // Perform work prior to dialog closing (maybe prompting "are you sure?")
}

private void MyClosedHandler(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // Perform work after the dialog has closed
}
```

Comment: Oh...is it so..then no other way to do this. can we customize?? b'coz i want to call some other functions if user closes the GroupBox Control.

Comment: @Vinay How is the user going to close the box? Do you provide an additional control that allows them to do that? If not, then they *can't* close it.

Comment: my appl. is in windows, grpbox contains uname and pwd with login and cancel btn's. so both the click events are handled. but suppose if user clicks on 'Close' then there is no event for this. i want to call some other functions if User selects 'Close'.

Comment: Oh, so you want to handle the closing of the *dialog* box. *That* you can do. I'll update my answer.

Comment: So it turns out that you wished to close the window or dialog than the group box.

Comment: yes. but here there is one pblm. as we defined the handler in form constructor....even user won't clicks on the close or cancel btn...MyClosingHandler() is called. I want this shld be called only on cancel/close...? how to restrict this?

Comment: @Vinay You can set a flag when you're closing the form in the "correct" way. In your handler, if the flag isn't set, you know it's been cancelled/closed/etc.

Comment: yes. but for cancel we can set but for 'Close' how to set the flag??

Comment: @Vinay You don't set it for either of those cases. Only set the flag if you *don't* want special processing to happen (like on OK, for example.) If the flag isn't set, then the user either clicked cancel or close.